How can I design a galvanically isolated power supply?
How do I design a galvanically isolated lower supply:

Input: 5V to 25V DC
Output: 5V 5A DC

I generally use reference designs to design a power supply or power supply design like TI workbench, etc. It is needed for an IOT gateway project.

This seems like a pretty vague question - can you give more details on what you're having issues with? TI's WeBench tool seems to give some pretty reasonably options assuming a 1A output, with one option based around the LM25184.

Do you have specific efficiency, accuracy, or noise constraints that make those inadequate? There's also a bunch of off-the-shelf modules available.

You can probably buy a module that does it for you. It will be cheaper than your time designing and validating one.

There is nothing wrong with using the workbench or reference design to get started on a design.
In this power range I would select a fly-back converter topology. for one because I know how they work, and because there is plenty of literature on them. Additionally I would choose to run the converter in discontinuous mode and voltage control mode because it is less complex than current control (in my opinion at least).
Next I would get a catalog of every transformer I can buy that has an isolation rating high enough to suit my application. I cool place to look is wuerth or pulse or Ti.
The key parameters I need are the primary and secondary inductance and the primary saturation current. The turns ratio could be used to compute the Inductance in a pinch.
I would compute the maximum power point under the worst case input conditions for a theoretical lossless fly-back converter using each transformer.
This will be when the converter is just running in discontinuous mode (also called critical conduction mode). or when the on-time + off-time is equal to the switching period. This will also be when the input voltage is lowest.
something like:
Isat = saturation current of the primary
Lp = primary inductance
Ls = secondary inductance
Vp = Primary voltage (input voltage)
Vs = Secondary voltage (output voltage)

D = 1/((Vp/Vs)*math.sqrt(Ls/Lp) + 1) # duty cycle at max power (between 0 and 1)
P = 0.5 * Vp * D * Isat # max power in W
F = Vp * D / (Isat * Lp) # frequency at max power in Hz

I would write a python script to compute these values for me for each core.
I would then select a transformer where the maximum transferable power at the lowest (worst case) input voltage is higher than the requirement by some realistic margin. Remember, the calculations are based on an idea converter so we will need some headroom for the losses of realistic components. This approach works, because any converter that makes sense using will have reasonable efficiency.
The calculation would output the duty cycle and frequency at which power transfer is highest.
I would then find a fly-back controller that can handle the switching frequency.
I would then model the circuit in ltspice and start characterizing the new theoretical converter. I would set different input voltages across the entire specified input range and also select various output loads. I'd play with different output capacitors, switching mosfets, fly-back diodes, and in general just find out if the converter makes any sense at all.
I would also experiment with stepped loads to determine if the feedback loop and regulation characteristics is good enough for my application.
If it turns out the transformer isn't the right choice, I'd go back and pick a different one and start over.
When all that is done I lay it out on a pcb, order components, and send the design files off to some pcb-fab.
Then I'd put it together and test it in real life... repeating the scenarios I had in the simulations.
This will get you a working converter... What we haven't discussed is cost optimization, how to guarantee reliability, regulatory compliance, electromagnetic interference tests, safety ... A bunch of stuff. Mind you we haven't designed a case for it yet...
But at that point you would have built a 25 Watt fly-back converter, and possibly a really garbage radio that will make your neighbors mad.

I am wondering as your breakdown seems pretty detailed.. At which point would you include parasitics and the choice of the snubber topology? I usually simulate before component selection because the simulation (especially regarding snubber stuff) can cause a total design reconsideration..But that could be my limited experience with switch mode converters.

You are absolutely right. And I would end up reiterating several times. A more experienced engineer could probably pick the right components faster.

A laundry list of specifications is required.
I was going to comment some of this, but in the spirit of "answering a question with a question", and that it's likely illustrative to readers, I'll list here, some of the specifications a power supply requires:

Input voltage range (✓)
Input transients (impedance, magnitude, duration, statistics)
Output voltage range/tolerance (mean voltage ✓)
Load transients (acceptable output impedance, at what frequencies; or voltage range/tolerance for what load current step)
Fault behavior (input over/under voltage, output overcurrent, temperature, etc.)
Isolation barrier (continuous voltage, impulse and statistics; capacitance)
EMC: emissions, susceptibility, at what amplitude in what frequency bands, etc.
Safety (basic/reinforced/etc. insulation?)
Noise or ripple (input and output, in what bands)
Operating temperature range (ambient air, conduction cooled, airflow available, etc.)
Environmental conditions: humidity, dust, water spray, etc.

Note that some of these affect mechanical moreso than electronic design, or can be handled by steps on top of the electronic design (e.g. conformal coating of the PCB to provide environmental immunity; this isn't specified in PCB fab files, but a separate assembly drawing).  Since "design" (unqualified) was asked, I would be inclined to take this to include all aspects of design, from specification into production.
